For PhD admissions, do I need an LOR from a current PI in addition to former PIs?
I am applying to USA PhDs and have three strong letters of recommendation from immediate former PIs who directly supervised my work. How essential is a recommendation from my current PI? During my interview for the research specialist role in my current position, my PI mentioned that the position would span two years, though no formal contract was signed. I have been with the lab for four months now. Should I ask my PI for a LOR, or would the three letters from my former supervisors suffice?

The best letters (US perspective) are from those who know you well and can honestly and accurately predict your likelihood of success in doctoral study and beyond. Given that the new PI may not know you as well, at the moment, that the others might be better. But you need to judge that.
And, if you think that the new PI would be greatly disturbed by your leaving (doubtful, actually) then they might not be the best source.
If you are unsuccessful in the current round, then the importance of letters from the new PI might be increased as they will know you better then.
Note that the answer of David Raven gives important notes about the case where you are chasing (sub) fields. Don't neglect that advice. Good luck.

Okay thank you so much !!

If your past research, current research, and future research are all in the same field, I would choose the strongest 3 letters.
Your current PI can still give a strong letter, by saying great things, while explaining that you haven't been working together for long. For example, they can explain why they are excited to work with you; that you are knowledgeable about X, have already contributed to Y, and are quickly learning how to do Z.
If you think this PI will write such a letter, and that it would be stronger than a previous PI's letter, then I would go for it.

If your past research areas differ substantially from your current and future research (which I presume align), I think you should strongly consider asking the current PI for a letter, even if a former PI can give a stronger one. However, if you think it may actively be a bad letter, then it is probably best to not ask for a letter.

I wanted to ask how important a letter of recommendation from my current PI would be, given that I’ve only been in the role for 4 months. During my job interview, my PI mentioned he expects me to stay for 2 years, and I’m applying for PhD admissions this year, which he doesn’t expect. I already have LORs from three immediate former PIs I’ve worked with. Would it be fine if I don't ask my current PI for a recommendation? - @David Raveh

Okay noted, thank you for the detailed response, it definitely helps. Would it impact my application if I choose not to ask my current PI for a letter, given that I have 2 strong LORs from my former PIs?
